# Qiskit: Getting weird error on creating an operator acting on certain qubits

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I have a system of `N` qubits and I want to construct a quantum operator `ZZ...ZZ` of length `j-(i+1)` such that it acts from qubits `i+1` to `j-1`. Taking a cue from [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15030/19840) answer I did the following

```
i,j,N=2,8,10
op = Operator.from_label('I'*(j-i-1))
opZ = Operator.from_label('Z'*(j-i-1))
op = op._add(opZ,qargs=list(range(i+1, j)))
```

I am getting the following error which makes no sense to me

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 op = Operator.from_label('I'*(j-i-1))
      2 opZ = Operator.from_label('Z'*(j-i-1))
----> 3 op = op._add(opZ,qargs=list(range(i+1, j)))

File ~/git/Deuteron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/operator.py:348, in Operator._add(self, other, qargs)
    345     other = Operator(other)
    347 self._op_shape._validate_add(other._op_shape, qargs)
--> 348 other = ScalarOp._pad_with_identity(self, other, qargs)
    350 ret = copy.copy(self)
    351 ret._data = self.data + other.data

File ~/git/Deuteron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/scalar_op.py:248, in ScalarOp._pad_with_identity(current, other, qargs)
    246 if qargs is None:
    247     return other
--> 248 return ScalarOp(current.input_dims()).compose(other, qargs=qargs)

File ~/git/Deuteron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/scalar_op.py:130, in ScalarOp.compose(self, other, qargs, front)
    121     return self.coeff * ret
    123 # For qargs composition we initialize the scalar operator
    124 # as an instance of the other BaseOperators subclass. We then
    125 # perform subsystem qargs composition using the BaseOperator
   (...)
    128 # not support initialization from a ScalarOp or the ScalarOps
    129 # `to_operator` method).
--> 130 return other.__class__(self).compose(other, qargs=qargs, front=front)

File ~/git/Deuteron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/operator.py:278, in Operator.compose(self, other, qargs, front)
    275 indices = [num_indices - 1 - qubit for qubit in qargs]
    276 final_shape = [np.product(output_dims), np.product(input_dims)]
    277 data = np.reshape(
--> 278     Operator._einsum_matmul(tensor, mat, indices, shift, right_mul), final_shape
    279 )
    280 ret = Operator(data, input_dims, output_dims)
    281 ret._op_shape = new_shape

File ~/git/Deuteron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/operator.py:451, in Operator._einsum_matmul(cls, tensor, mat, indices, shift, right_mul)
    449 else:
    450     indices_mat = mat_free + mat_contract
--> 451 return np.einsum(tensor, indices_tensor, mat, indices_mat)

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in einsum(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/git/Deuteron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py:1359, in einsum(out, optimize, *operands, **kwargs)
   1357     if specified_out:
   1358         kwargs['out'] = out
-> 1359     return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
   1361 # Check the kwargs to avoid a more cryptic error later, without having to
   1362 # repeat default values here
   1363 valid_einsum_kwargs = ['dtype', 'order', 'casting']

ValueError: subscript is not within the valid range [0, 52)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct an $N$-qubit operator that acts as $ZZ...Z$ from qubit $i+1$ to $j-1$, you can simply do the following:

```
i,j,N=2,8,10

label = 'I'*(i+1) + 'Z'*(j-i-1) + 'I'*(N-j)
print(label) # <= Check!
op = Operator.from_label(label)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the order be the other way around? From Qiskit documentation - "In the string representation qubit-0 corresponds to the right-most Pauli character, and qubit-(n−1) to the left-most Pauli character. For example 'XYZ' represents X⊗Y⊗Z with 'Z' on qubit-0, 'Y' on qubit-1, and 'X' on qubit-3."